# How to highlight parts of webpages in Chrome browser, and save for later?

Tags: chrome, bookmark, annotation

How to highlight webpages in Google chrome browser and save it for in case to re review at later time.

i need an extension (or anything else which will fulfill the solution) and will highlight important parts of webpage as i read for to review it later, i mean the whole page not part of it. should be hassle free.

Answer (score 1):

[Evernote Webclipper](https://evernote.com/webclipper/) to the rescue

It gives you options not just to clip the whole page but all the options from taking screenshots to just clipping a certain part of a webpage or highlighting certain texts, organizing all your clips, sharing your clips etc.

Comment: i am a member of evernote but i cannot highlight parts of webpage when its in full page modes but in Screenshot mode.

Answer (score 0):

There are many highlighter extensions available on the Chrome Web Store. Just to name a few:

- [Weava](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/weava-highlighter-pdf-web/cbnaodkpfinfiipjblikofhlhlcickei?hl=en): unlimited highlights with cloud sync for free
- [Snippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snippet-highlighter-web-p/fkaokedhimpifhfadmgjpfjimkogdlcm?hl=en): free unlimited highlighting with notes; highlights are copied into a Google Keep–like interface